# How can I just use high order functions to rewrite these (use Dr.Racket)

Tags: racket, higher-order-functions

This is my homework but we are only allowed to use **filter, map, foldr, sort, build-list, and lambda instead of the explicit recursion**

How can I rewrite these use those high order functions above to not let the function call itself.

What I have now are these:

````
(define (worthless loc name)
  (cond
    [(empty? loc) loc]
    [(equal? name (coin-name (first loc))) (cons (make-coin (coin-name (first loc)) 0) (worthless (rest loc) name))]
    [else (cons (first loc) (worthless (rest loc) name))]))

(define (working-group locations group-tz)
  (cond
    [(empty? locations) empty]
    [(and (equal? (utc-hours group-tz) (utc-hours (location-timezone (first locations)))) (equal? (utc-sign group-tz) (utc-sign (location-timezone (first locations)))))
     (cons (location-city (first locations)) (working-group (rest locations) group-tz))]
    [(and (equal? (add1 (utc-hours group-tz)) (utc-hours (location-timezone (first locations))))
          (equal? (utc-sign group-tz) (utc-sign (location-timezone (first locations))))
          (equal? (utc-mins group-tz) (utc-mins (location-timezone (first locations)))))
     (cons (location-city (first locations)) (working-group (rest locations) group-tz))]
    [(and (equal? (sub1 (utc-hours group-tz)) (utc-hours (location-timezone (first locations))))
          (equal? (utc-sign group-tz) (utc-sign (location-timezone (first locations))))
          (equal? (utc-mins group-tz) (utc-mins (location-timezone (first locations)))))
     (cons (location-city (first locations)) (working-group (rest locations) group-tz))]
    [else (working-group (rest locations) group-tz)])) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `worthless` can be rewritten with `map`. Imagine we have this function that adds 3 to each element in a list:

```
(define (add3 lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (+ (car lst) 3)
            (add3 (cdr lst)))))
```

Map for one list looks like this:

```
(define (map f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (f (car lst))
            (map f (cdr lst))))
```

Looking at these you can see that an `add3` with map only needs to focus on adding 3. Basically you need to pass a function with one argument that adds 3 to that argument:

```
(define (add3-wm lst)
  (map (lambda (v) (+ v 3)) lst))
```

Now `foldr` for one list looks like this:

```
(define (foldr f init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (f (car lst)
         (foldr f init (cdr lst)))))
```

Here you see that `cons` isn't done so rewriting `add3` using `foldr` takes a combiner and it needs to add 3 to the first argument and combine the two arguments where the second argument is the result fo the same process with the later elements.

```
(define (add3-fr lst)
  (define (combiner v acc)
    (cons (+ v 3) acc))
  (foldr combiner '() lst))
```

In reality using `foldr` here is overkill, but it would be interesting if you sometimes needed to skip an element like `working-group` does. In that case the combiner just returns the second argument. You can make `filter` with `foldr`:

```
(define (filter f lst)
  (foldr (lambda (v acc)
           (if (f v)
               (cons v acc)
               acc))
         '()
         lst))
```

Good luck